# React Axios requests are not possible when accessing React from another computer in the same network

Tags: reactjs, flask, axios

I built a simple demo cinema management application with React.js and Flask.

The React movies component in which all the the cinema movies ( Fetched from Flask ) are displayed, works just fine - as long as I access the React url **from the same computer** (http://localhost:3000/movies ).

When I try to access React from another computer in my network, using the source computer IP which in my case is 10.0.0.14 ( http://10.0.0.14:3000/movies ), although React is working, I can't make axios API calls and I get the following error.

```
GET http://localhost:5000/movies net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
Uncaught (in promise) AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
xhr.js:220 GET http://localhost:5000/movies net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Now, This is the part of my React code from which requests are made

```
  useEffect(() =>
  {
    async function getMovies()
    {
      let resp = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/movies/");
      setMovies;
    }
    getMovies()

  },[])
```

This is my Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask
import json
from bson import ObjectId

from flask_cors import CORS

from routers.persons import persons

class JSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj) :
        if isinstance(obj, ObjectId):
            return str(obj)
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self,obj)

app = Flask(__name__)

CORS(app)

app.url_map.strict_slashes = False

app.json_encoder = JSONEncoder


app.register_blueprint(persons, url_prefix="/movies/")


app.run()
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix this and allow axios requests when accessing React from another device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your API call of the react app. You are using localhost even you are doing the api call from a different host browser. Change the localhost to the api host ip then it will work.

Change this to `http://localhost:5000/movies/` to `http://<api-ip-address>:5000/movies/`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! that's the solution